# How can I reduce sodium chloride levels in water, without removing other minerals?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, water-treatment, minerals

How can I reduce sodium chloride levels in water, without removing other minerals?
Good day,
I make a sole from Himalayan Salt which I add to my Reverse Osmosis treated water to ensure my body isn't rob of essential minerals, but the levels of sodium chloride are very high. How would I remove some of the NaCl without affecting the other minerals?

Comment: What you are asking is not possible using any conventional system that you would be able to obtain. Your only real solution is to take a different approach. Buy the individual salts (e.g., KCl, NaCl, CaCO3) and make a mixture yourself.

Comment: If you remove the NaCl from Himalayan salt there isn't much left.

Comment: Other than fluoride, drinking water is **not** a useful source of minerals. You get all you need from a normal diet. As for fluoride, most toothpastes and some mouthwashes contain supplements.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a major component does not make sense. Better is to balance it with other ions, as $\ce{K+, Ca^2+, Mg^2+, HCO3-, H2PO4-, SO4^2- }$.
But the gain and safety to provide nutrients by the form of dissolved salts is questionable. I think, providing minor mineral nutrients by $\ce{NaCl}$ of whatever origin is a bad idea in the first place.